# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'bookDto' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with spring boot and thymeleaf and I keep getting the "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name `bookDto` available as request attribute" when I return the index page after successful login

The weird thing is that the index page works fine when I search  for it as `localhost:8080/index`.

I have also tried returning another page from login method and its only the index page giving me the error.

Below are my controllers methods and the index.html form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
@PostMapping
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult bindignResult) {   

    AppUser userLoggedIn = userService.findByUserNameAndEncryptedPassword(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword());

    if (userLoggedIn == null){
            modelAndView.addObject("errorLogin", "Incorrect Credentials!");
            modelAndView.setViewName("signin");

    }else {
             modelAndView.setViewName("index");
         }

     return modelAndView;
}
```

filters books by their attributes

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
 @PostMapping
 public ModelAndView searchBooks(@ModelAttribute ("bookDto") BookDto bookDto, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("books", bookService.listAll(searchFilterBuilder.buildFilter(bookDto)));
    model.addAttribute("bookDto", bookDto);
    return new ModelAndView("index");

  }
```

and finally my  in index.html

```
   <form th:object="${bookDto}" th:action="@{/search}" method="post">
```

Comment: where you have declared bean for BookDto?

Comment: I'm not sure sure what you mean, but BookDto is not a bean, it's just pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookDto is sent as the request body so you have to get it like this

```
public ModelAndView searchBooks(BookDto bookDto, Model model) {
```

Simply remove @ModelAttribute

But you have to make sure that bookDto get's initialized!
So when you are navigating to the index page you have to create a new BookDto:

```
modelAndView.setViewName("index");
model.addAttribute("bookDto", new BookDto());
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, but it still gives me the same error.  I added @ModelAttribute since bookDto is populated in view and used to filter books by attributes

Comment: And how is bookDto generated the first time when you navigate to the search page?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough since I didn't send the whole code. My index page is the one that contains two Input fields to search my books (by title and year), this is where I need my bookDto , and below is the list of all my books from database.

Comment: I have already done that. The index page works fine. The error arises when I return the index page after user is logged in .I have already provided the code for login method at the beginning

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you are right. I haven't initialized BookDto in login method. Thank you for your help